# How can I run windows service to schedule a job which will pick time from database to execute?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a process for sending email which will send the email automatically at a specific time  using windows services and time is fixed in code. But I want this process to take the time from database. Is it possible??

I had tried to make the window service take time from database but didn't find anything for this. Now I want to make this window service to connect with ms sql and take the time from table in database.

Comment: make your service always running and read the time from database on start and then then raise a event on the schedule time and do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can set up your service to always run and read the time from the database at startup, then trigger an event at the scheduled time and get the job done.